# WIN8 dialogue window not opening with tab navigation enabled - pyautogui

Tags: python, pyautogui

I'm using `pyautogui` to automate routines in SAP2000 under Windows8

Everything is fine using `alt+shortcuts` etc.

I can also use `tab` to navigate buttons. Except for a particular dialogue box where `tab` navigation seems to be disabled upon dialogue box opening.

If I click on any item, then `tab` navigation becomes accessible. But I don't want to use the mouse so that my script be consistent across different screen sizes etc.

Here a screen shot of the dialogue box upon opening (`tab` navigation not accessible)

[image: <code>tab</code> navigation disabled upon dialogue box opening]

And here after mouse click on an item (enables `tab` navigation)

[image: <code>tab</code> navigation enabled after mouse click]

Any ideas on how I can activate `tab` navigation without using the mouse?